# IIS Version 10.0 - Requests are stuck in worker process with state RequestAcquireState - Module is session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, request, iis-10

On our server we have IIS 10.0

Application hosted is AP.Net MVC Framework 4.7.2

In worker process many times requests are stuck

Majority time stuck requests are with State - RequestAcquireState

And module name is Session

Many times it is making site slower.

To overcome from this we are restarting specific application and recycling app pool

But this chance we are not getting everytime.

Can somebody please help to understand and solve this issue without restarting service ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Access to the `Session` object in ASP.Net is controlled in a way where only one request with write access to the session can be active at any one time. Are you doing lots of ajax request? Do all the requests need write access to the session? See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v%3Dvs.100)). Scroll down to sub heading _Concurrent Requests and Session State_

Answer (score 2):

By default ASP.NET locks on session. All concurrent requests in Asp.net are controlled by the session management. As long as there is a request in `ExecuteRequestHandler` that locks the session and thus all other subsequent requests will be locked.
Please refer to the following discussion for more details.
[Requests hanging on Session module on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570855/requests-hanging-on-session-module-on-iis-7-5)
https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/concurrent-requests-in-asp-net-mvc